# Relations between $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt{x+n}$

Tags: arithmetic, fractional-part

Is there any relation between $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt{x+n}$? I am interested in the fractional part mostly.

n and x are both positive integers, n is much greater than x.

Comment: What do you mean by Fractional part?

Comment: Are both $x$ and $n$ non-negative integers, non-negative real numbers, mixed, both variable or one variable, . . . ?

Comment: For $x\gg n$ you can approximate $\sqrt{x+n}$ as $(1+\frac n{2x})\sqrt x$. Is that the kind of thing you're asking for?

Comment: Both are non-negative integers. X is given.

Comment: By fractional part i mean the number after the decimal notation.

Comment: if $x \gg n$ means much greater, than no, they are pretty close in most cases, but that might help anyway, thanks.

Comment: Actually I think n is graeter than x in most cases, so that might not work

Comment: But then what you're effectively asking is for a relation between $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt y$ where $x$ and $y$ are both integers and one is much larger than the other. I don't think there's any interesting answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate $\int_x^{x+n} 1(/\sqrt{t})dt$ you get $2(\sqrt{x+n} - \sqrt{x})$ which for large $x$ compared to $n$ is a good approximation to the integral and so the difference $\sqrt{x+n} - \sqrt{x}$ is comparable to $(n/2)/\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I think in most of my cases n is greater than x, buth thanks anyway. I might be able to use this.

Comment: i checked again. n is much greater than x.